# Two many-to-one relationships referencing the same column NHibernate

Tags: c#, mysql, nhibernate

Have been looking around for the past half-day & have come up dry. Essentially, I'm working on a legacy app, the preexisting NHibernate configuration mapped a single property / column on the DB-end to two different "many-to-one" relations, and thus two different C# properties. The tables `categories` and `types` share the same primary keys / indexes, but there's no explicit relationship in MySQL or NHibernate.

Previously these tables have been "read-only" and it's worked in the application while avoiding exposing this as an issue. But, I've been recently tasked with allowing users to modify and persist changes to the `grid` table (has other properties I've not listed for brevity).

NHibernate threw a cryptic exception relating, I believe, to the fact that it's trying to save two separate "Domain" level objects to a single column reference. I looked through the `general_log` and the update query didn't reach the database. Commenting out the "Cat" line in the `.hbm.xml` config file resolved the "error", but how can I fix the mapping such that `Cat` and `GridType` need to have the same `ID` value and I can persist `grid` changes back to the DB?

```
public class Grid
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual GridType GridType { get; set; }
    public virtual Cat Cat { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

The DB schema looks like this (maintaining existing weird setup):

```
CREATE TABLE `categories` 
  `CatID` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`CatID`)

CREATE TABLE `types`
  `TypeID` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  `Name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`TypeID`)

CREATE TABLE `grid` 
  `GridID` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `TypeID` smallint(4) NOT NULL,
  ...
  PRIMARY KEY (`GridID`),
  KEY `GridTypeId` (`TypeID`),
  CONSTRAINT `GridTypeId` FOREIGN KEY (`TypeID`) REFERENCES `types` (`TypeID`),
```

The table `grid` references the table `types` via a foreign key in MySQL, but nothing on the DB-end ties it to `categories`. The NHibernate configuration is currently set up like this with the only exception being previously the "grid" configuration was previously `mutable="false"` and `cache usage="read-only"`:

```
  <class name="Grid, Domain" table="grid" lazy="true">
    <cache usage="read-write" />
    <id name="Id" column="GridID" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    ...
    <many-to-one name="GridType" column="TypeID" fetch="join" not-null="true" />
    <many-to-one name="Cat" column="TypeID" not-null="true" />
  </class>

  <class name="Cat, Domain" table="categories" lazy="true" mutable="false">
    <cache usage="read-only"/>
    <id name="Id" column="CatID" unsaved-value="0">
      <generator class="identity" />
    </id>
    <property name="Name" />
    ...
  </class>

  <class name="GridType, Domain" table="types" mutable="false">
    <cache usage="read-only"/>
    <id name="Id" column="TypeID"/>
    <property name="Name" />
    ...
  </class>
```

Will try and convince my boss that this is worth restructuring, because this whole area of the DB is a mess, but this *is* a legacy application; so I want to know what my options are depending on what our availability for future development looks like.

---

**Edit**: Trialing what Radim Köhler suggested below. Only hiccup was that (a) Someone could switch the value of `Cat` and errantly believe they'd made a change to the DB, but it won't be persisted. And (b) if someone updated `GridType`, it'd update the DB but not the cache; `Cat` would remain the old value until NHibernate pulled back from the DB again (i.e. IDs of `Cat` and `GridType` would be "de-synced" which was part of my question).

Fix I'm trialing is "when the GridType / Cat values on Grid are set, set the other one by fetching the appropriate ID from cache". Will also prevent someone from setting a gridtype / cat that may not exist in the other table.

```
public class Grid {

    ...

    private GridType _gridType;
    private Cat _cat;

    public virtual GridType GridType
    {
        get => _gridType;
        set
        {
            var cat = _catRepository.GetById(value.Id);
            _cat = cat ?? throw new InvalidOperationException("GridType is not valid Cat");
            _gridType = value;
        }
    }
```

And repeat the above for `public virtual Cat Cat`. If anyone sees an issue with this, please feel free to leave a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use one column in mapping for multiple purposes... but only one *property* can be editable ... all other must be readonly. We can use `insert="false" update="false"`

This would work in our case:

```
<many-to-one name="GridType" column="TypeID" ... />
<many-to-one name="Cat"      column="TypeID" insert="false" update="false" />
```

Comment: I thought about this, and it _nearly_ resolves my issue. The only problem seems to be a caching issue, where if I update `GridType` and not `Cat` and commit the transaction, then the column gets correctly updated on the DB side, `GridType` is correct, but `Cat` remains the same until the cache is refreshed. I think I can either programmatically update `Cat` in the app whenever `GridType` is changed / fiddle with the cache for that property specifically & make this work. Thanks for the suggestion.